# Como puedo hacer que mi controlador solo acepte peticiones de mi aplicación echa en ionic? Laravel5.8

Tags: laravel, ajax, ionic4

Tengo una api contruida en laravel, que la consumo desde una aplicacion movil echa en ionic v4.. todo funciona bien excepto por un problema en la seguridad...
Si yo escribo en la url de mi navegador `https://midominio/api/incio` me devuelve el json de mi funcion...
Lo que yo quiero hacer es que si detecta que no es un peticion ajax que redirija al inicio
probe esto: `if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');` pero no funciona

mi metodo:

```
public function show($id) {
    $empresa = Empresa::findOrFail($id);
    $ciudad=Ciudad::where('ciu_id', $empresa->ciudad_ciu_id)->first();
    $categoria=Categoria::where('cat_id', $empresa->categoria_cat_id)->first();
    return [
        "empresa" => $empresa, 
        "ciudad" => $ciudad, 
        "categoria" => $categoria
    ];
}
```

mi peticion desde ionic v4

```
buscarEmpresa(ciudad?, categoria?, texto?, cargar?){
if (cargar == 0) {
  this.paginaBusqueda = 1;
}
if (cargar == 1) {
  this.paginaBusqueda ++;
}
console.log('cargar2: '+cargar);
console.log('pagina: '+this.paginaBusqueda);

return this.http.get(`${ URL }/api/inicio?page=${ this.paginaBusqueda }&busciudad=${ ciudad }&buscategoria=${ categoria }&searchText=${ texto }`);
```

}

Comment: Deberias tener un metodo de autenticación para acceder a tu informacion. Puedes investigar oAuth (Laravel Passport). Otra alternativa, puedes ser que en tus cabeceras en la peticion desde Ionic envies alguna cabecera encriptada que puedas desencriptar desde tu backend y verificar si es valida

Comment: La idea es que mis usuarios no necesiten autenticarse... creo que no hice mi pregunta correctamente por lo que no entiendes mi problema..

Comment: Si, por eso te di la otra alternativa. Enviar una cabecera con algún valor encriptado mediante bcrypt podría ser. Del lado de Laravel crear un middleware que lea ese valor en la cabecera, verifique que es correcta y deje llamar al controlador.